# Class "Google_Service_MyBusiness" not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-my-business-api

I use Google My Business API to fetch the account list, but it shows the following error.

> "Class "Google_Service_MyBusiness" not found."

In my Laravel project, I am using Google Analytics, and its classes are working correctly. I installed the `google/apiclient": "2.12"` package. Do I need to install any other libraries to access my Google My Business account?

```
$mybusinessService = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;
$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, FYI: The GMB API will be deprecated as it is to be replaced by the new Business Profile APIs (https://developers.google.com/my-business/ref_overview).

The new APIs are part of the [Google PHP API Client Services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services).

In order to list accounts via the Account Management API (`google-api-php-client-services/src/MyBusinessAccountManagement/`), I suggest you take a look at [Accounts.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/blob/6692549efd68dfa84e0761e5e733d7aee09b7d50/src/MyBusinessAccountManagement/Resource/Accounts.php).

Comment: Thank you,  vpriesner,  it is working properly, now i am getting account information.